# Fork() and parent/child processes

Tags: c, linux, fork

This is the question on my homework and what the teacher expects as output...I am confused as to where to go from here I have included my code.  My output is both the child process and parent process in the thousands

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

main()
{
/* Create three variables */
/* One to create a fork */
/* One to store a value */
/* One to use as a count control for a loop */

/* Initialize value variable here */ ;

printf("Ready to fork...\n");

/* Create fork here */

if ( /* Condition to determine if parent */ )
{
        printf( "The child executes this code.\n" );
        for (  /* Count control variable set to zero, less than five, incremented */  )
         /* Value variable */  =  /* What does value variable equal? */ ;
        printf( "Child = /* The ending value variable goes here */ " );
     }
else
    {
         for (  /* Count control variable set to zero, less than five, incremented */  )
            /* Value variable */  =  /* What does value variable equal? */ ;
        printf("Parent = /* The ending value variable goes here */ ");

    }
}

Here is the output from my program:
Ready to fork...
The parent executes this code.
Parent = 3
The child executes this code.
Child = 10
```

This is what my code is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

main()
{
/* Create three variables */
int frk;
int val;
int count;

val=0;

printf("Ready to fork...\n");

frk=fork();

if ( frk==0 )
{
                printf( "The child executes this code.\n" );
                for (count=0; count<5; count++  )
                val  = frk ;
                printf( "Child = %d\n",val );
         }
else
        {
                 for (count=0; count<5; count++  )
                val  =  frk;
                printf("Parent = %d\n ",val);

        }
}
```

Comment: `if (frk=0)` - anything look "not C like" to you there?

Comment: frk==0 I completely missed that

Comment: Its not "syntax error" and still a valid C statement, but John already points to the typo mistake.

Comment: Even after that I end up with incorrect values for child and parent. Parent is in the thousands and child is 0.

Comment: @Josamoda: Your compiler should warn you about `if ( frk=0 )` typos. Try this [Makefile](https://gist.github.com/zed/7982358) (just put it with your *.c file and run `make`)

Comment: @Josamoda: `frk` is a child's `pid` in the parent and zero in the child. Your teacher might expect you to use `count` to calculate `val` e.g., `val = 2*(count + 1)` in the child.

Comment: But what exactly would cause parent to = 3?

Comment: I honestly can't think of any way you could arrive at that result. I'm pretty sure that the exercise is faulty - it may be assuming that local variables are shared across a `fork()`, which is not the case!

Comment: @duskwuff: `val = count - 1` in the parent would produce `3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exercise as it is written is kind of confusing, but it seems to me that what the author is getting at is this:

Your program includes a single "value" variable: let's call it `val`.

After your program calls `fork()`, the child process should set `val` to 10 while the parent process sets it to 3. This works because the child and parent processes have different address spaces; even though they are both running the same code, the name `val` refers to different locations in memory for the child process and parent process.

In other words, you don't need to expect `fork()` to return 3 or 10. After you run a short `for(...)` loop, you can just have the parent process set `val = 3` and have the child process set `val = 10`.

```
if (frk == 0) {
    ...
    val = 10;
    printf("Child = %d\n", val);
}
else {
    ...
    val = 3;
    printf("Parent = %d\n", val);
}
```